# Hola, como puedo lanzar una función cuando se deje de oprimir teclas en vue.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

ya intente con esto pero no me funciona.

```
<input type="text" v-model="text" v-on:keypress="ejecuta()">

<script>
export default {
   data() {
   text: '',
   },
   methods: {
    ejecuta(){
      var intervalo;
      clearInterval(intervalo);
      intervalo = setInterval(function () {
        alert('se dejo de escribir');
        clearInterval(intervalo);

      }, 2000);
    }
   }
}
</script>
```

Esto lo quiero hacer para auto guardar lo que el usuario escriba, pero tampoco quiero generar una petición cada que el usuario presione una tecla.

Comment: En ves de trabajar con intervalos trata con el evento v-on:change para lanzar la petición y mira si satisface tu necesidad

Comment: Lo termine resolviendo con una función de lodsh que se llama debounce. Gracias...